# Views are Lost when sliding Back in ViewPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-pageradapter

Don't know why but My PagerAdapter is behaving quite weird, when I am sliding back to my previous pages the pages are lost(not renderer)
 I tried few suggestions on Stackoverflow but those were not helpful for me, this is my code for Adapter:

```
 class MyPager extends PagerAdapter {
 int size;
 ArrayList<GridView> GridArrayList;

 public MyPager( ArrayList<GridView> GridArrayList) {
 size=GridArrayList.size();
 this.GridArrayList = GridArrayList;
 }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
 return size;
 }

 public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
 Log.d("position", "" + position);
 GridView gridView = GridArrayList.get(position);
 container.addView(gridView);
 return gridView;
 }

 @Override
 public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
 ((ViewPager)container).removeView((GridView) object);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
 return view == ((GridView) object);
}
}
```

Is there any bug in my code or something missing, Any help will be appreciated,

 thanks to all Readers

Comment: -Add @Override to instantiateItem function.
-Are you using setOffscreenPageLimit to your viewPager?

Comment: Adding @Override to instantiateItem function and using pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0) are not giving any solution

Comment: thank you friend by your suggestion I set pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(GridArrayList.size)  so now problem is solved, thank you very much @nnn